# For repeated-measures ANOVA, is there a benefit to averaging the data of participants?

Tags: bayesian, anova, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, repeated-measures

I'm creating a psychology experiment where participants will all perform the same task in which only one within-subject condition will vary (12°, 28° or 45°). Each condition will be presented 200 times (so 600 trials total).

I plan to do a Bayesian repeated-measures ANOVA to analyze my data. Since we have hypotheses about the direction of the effect, Bayesian t-tests between the different ° will also be performed with the hypothesis that performance is worse for 12° than 28° and worse for 28° compared to 45°.

So, I was wondering whether I should average the performance per condition (so for each subject I would get 3 data points) before performing the ANOVA or if I should keep the 600 data points per subject and perform the ANOVA by specifying which data point belongs to which condition.

My instinct (although I'm no statistician) would be to perform the latter in order not to lose the within-subject variance. However, my supervisor told me that it's usual in the field to perform the former so I'm a bit lost.

Thank you for your insights,

Best,
MC.